# Using mjackson's expect spyOn on function from React component's props

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, reactjs, enzyme

I'm getting an error `TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'onFocus' of object '#<Object>'` when I am trying to use expect spyOn on a function from props, probably because of spyOn behaviour.

```
it('handleFocus', () => {
      const wrapper = setup()
      const spy = spyOn(wrapper.props(), 'onFocus')
      wrapper.instance().handleFocus()
      expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled()
})
```

There is the setup function

```
const setup = (isMount) => {
    const props = {
      value: 'test',
      promise: () => Promise.resolve({}),
      access: () => {},
      onFocus: () => {},
      onChange: () => {},
      onUpdateInput: v => v
    }
    return isMount
      ? mount(<AutoCompleteAsync {...props} />)
      : shallow(<AutoCompleteAsync {...props} />)
  }
```

and there you can find the handleFocus function

```
handleFocus () {
    const { onFocus, onInputFocus } = this.props
    if (onInputFocus) {
      onInputFocus()
    }
    onFocus()
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

SpyOn tries to override your method with a mock.

> Replaces the method in target with a spy.
>   https://github.com/mjackson/expect#spyon

But your object is a shallow copy that Enzyme provides:

```
// That's what actually happens in your test, setup() aside
const wrapper = shallow(<AutoCompleteAsync {...props} />)
```

The only way to modify its props is by calling setProps again.

it('handleFocus', () => {
      const wrapper = setup()
      const props = {
         value: 'test',
         onFocus: () => {}
      }
      // Replace onFocus with spied onFocus
      const spy = spyOn(props, 'onFocus')

```
  // Inject spied onFocus back
  wrapper.setProps(props)
  wrapper.instance().handleFocus()
  expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled()
```

})

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't help, I have the same error.

Comment: Missed the fact that you mount the component. Updated my answer.

Comment: But I don't mount it in this test (and actually nowhere for now). Also your answer didn't change?

Comment: I don't really get why it has to be like that but it works. Thank you.